# External Interface not returning a variable which is a url generated from XML data

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Here's the problem: 
Basically I have some XML generated data which I'm pulling into flash. I'm using an ExternalInterface.call to export out some data to JavaScript in an Array. For some reason everything EXCEPT the url is getting returned - I've tried to trace the url - works fine. I've set a variable with a standard url in the same place - works fine.

So all in all it's extremely confusing!

Here's a snippet of the code to see if anyone can offer any advice!

```
    shedProductName = productName;
  shedColourName = new String(xmlData.data.item[clickedItem-1].product[name1].colours.colour.(@colour==colourCode2));  
  //shedColourImgLoc = new String(xmlData.data.item[clickedItem-1].product[name1].colours.colour.(@location));
  shedProdImgLoc = new String(xmlData.data.item[clickedItem-1].product[name1].@webimage); // this fails!
  trace(shedProdImgLoc); // this returns the correct result! :-S
  var testVar:String = new String("http://www.google.com"); // this works!!
  if (ExternalInterface.available) {
  flash.external.ExternalInterface.call("sendToJavaScript", [shedProductName, shedColourName, testVar, shedProdImgLoc]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the URL string before sending it.

```
...
var testVar:String = new String("http://www.google.com");
testVar = escape(testVar); 
...
```

This results in a string with all uncommon characters converted to URL-friendly equivalent, in this case it becomes:

> http%3A//www.google.com

I hope this helps!